# Configuring virtualhost and .htaccess on localhost using apache with linux ubuntu

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, localhost, virtualhost

i'm trying to configure a web site, "redspot.es" in localhost with apache server in a ubuntu linux distro. I want that this site can be accessed from localhost whithout writing the "localhost" word before his name (redspot.es) in the browser url.

When i try to access to redspot.es (on localhost) in the browser i get this:

```
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at redspot.es Port 80
```

i'm trying to find the reason of this:
i suspect that the problem may be in the .htaccess and the .conf config files:

I have this site placed in /var/www/redspot.es/public_html
.htaccess file is placed in /var/www/redspot.es and in /var/www/redspot.es/public_html:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>

AuthName redspot.es

#remove www de la url, si es que NO (!) es la url ya (^)(empieza por)rinconintangible.es ( y después, como no lleva $(fin), puede llevar cuales quiera cosas)
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^redspot\.es
#RewriteRule (.*) http://redspot.es/$1 [R=301]
# las 2 vlíneas anteriores las ocmento porque ya las hago en el htaccess de un nivel de carpetas superior, es decir, desde la carpeta /public_html/ del server

#remove index.php de la url http://redspot.es/index.php No lo quita de las que no acaban en index.php, ej: index.php?jsdjsdjs=ygg&hsbs=hhh
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ .*/index\.(php|html)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html)$ /$1 [R=301]
```

And the /etc/apache2/sites-available/redspot.es.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName redspot.es
    ServerAlias www.redspot.es
    ServerAdmin admin@redspot.es
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/redspot.es/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/html/redspot.es/public_html>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All  
        Order allow,deny 
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also i enable the site:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ sudo a2ensite redspot.es
```

And in the /etc/hosts i have this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   than-pc
192.168.1.137   redspot.es
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutioned. It seems to be that to place the website folder into the `/var/www/html` folder (/var/www/html/redspot.es/public_html/) is necessary